# Can I use a Request / Reply - RPC pattern in Rails 3 with AMQP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, rabbitmq, amqp

For reasons similar to the ones in [this discussion](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.networking.rabbitmq.general/13397), I'm experimenting with messaging in lieu of REST for a synchronous RPC call from one Rails 3 application to another. Both apps are running on thin.

The "server" application has a `config/initializers/amqp.rb` file based on the Request / Reply pattern in the [rubyamqp.info documentation](http://rubyamqp.info/articles/patterns_and_use_cases/#requestreply_pattern):

```
require "amqp"

EventMachine.next_tick do
  connection = AMQP.connect ENV['CLOUDAMQP_URL'] || 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost'
  channel    = AMQP::Channel.new(connection)

  requests_queue = channel.queue("amqpgem.examples.services.time", :exclusive => true, :auto_delete => true)
  requests_queue.subscribe(:ack => true) do |metadata, payload|
    puts "[requests] Got a request #{metadata.message_id}. Sending a reply..."
    channel.default_exchange.publish(Time.now.to_s,
                                     :routing_key    => metadata.reply_to,
                                     :correlation_id => metadata.message_id,
                                     :mandatory      => true)
    metadata.ack
  end

  Signal.trap("INT") { connection.close { EventMachine.stop } }
end
```

In the 'client' application, I'd like to render the results of a synchronous call to the 'server' in a view. I realize this is a bit outside the comfort zone of an inherently asynchronous library like the amqp gem, but I'm wondering if there's a way to make it work. Here is my client `config/initializers/amqp.rb`:

```
require 'amqp'

EventMachine.next_tick do
  AMQP.connection = AMQP.connect 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost'  
  Signal.trap("INT") { AMQP.connection.close { EventMachine.stop } }
end
```

Here is the controller:

```
require "amqp"

class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index    
    puts "[request] Sending a request..."

    WelcomeController.channel.default_exchange.publish("get.time",
      :routing_key => "amqpgem.examples.services.time",
      :message_id  => Kernel.rand(10101010).to_s,
      :reply_to    => WelcomeController.replies_queue.name)

    WelcomeController.replies_queue.subscribe do |metadata, payload|
      puts "[response] Response for #{metadata.correlation_id}: #{payload.inspect}"
      @message = payload.inspect
    end   
  end

  def self.channel
    @channel ||= AMQP::Channel.new(AMQP.connection)
  end

  def self.replies_queue
    @replies_queue ||= channel.queue("reply", :exclusive => true, :auto_delete => true)
  end
end
```

When I start both applications on different ports and visit the `welcome#index` view.
`@message` is nil in the view, since the result has not yet returned. The result arrives a few milliseconds after the view is rendered and is displayed on the console:

```
$ thin start
>> Using rack adapter
>> Thin web server (v1.5.0 codename Knife)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
[request] Sending a request...
[response] Response for 3877031: "2012-11-27 22:04:28 -0600"
```

No surprise here: `subscribe` is clearly not meant for synchronous calls. What is surprising is that I can't find a synchronous alternative in the AMQP gem source code or in any documentation online. Is there an alternative to `subscribe` that will give me the RPC behavior I want? Given that there are other parts of the system in which I'd want to use legitimately asynchronous calls, the [bunny gem](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/bunny) didn't seem like the right tool for the job. Should I give it another look?

**edit in response to Sam Stokes**

Thanks to Sam for the pointer to throw :async / async.callback. I hadn't seen this technique before and this is exactly the kind of thing I was trying to learn with this experiment in the first place. `send_response.finish` is gone in Rails 3, but I was able to get his example to work for at least one request with a minor change:

```
render :text => @message
rendered_response = response.prepare!
```

Subsequent requests fail with `!! Unexpected error while processing request: deadlock; recursive locking`. This may have been what Sam was getting at with the comment about getting ActionController to allow concurrent requests, but the cited gist only works for Rails 2. Adding `config.allow_concurrency = true` in development.rb gets rid of this error in Rails 3, but leads to `This queue already has default consumer.` from AMQP.

I think this yak is sufficiently shaven. ;-)

While interesting, this is clearly overkill for simple RPC. Something like this [Sinatra streaming example](https://gist.github.com/1476463) seems a more appropriate use case for client interaction with replies. Tenderlove also has [a blog post](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html) about an upcoming way to stream events in Rails 4 that could work with AMQP.

As Sam points out in his discussion of the HTTP alternative, REST / HTTP makes perfect sense for the RPC portion of my system that involves two Rails apps. There are other parts of the system involving more classic asynchronous event publishing to Clojure apps. For these, the Rails app need only publish events in fire-and-forget fashion, so AMQP will work fine there using my original code without the reply queue.

Comment: Thanks for figuring out the Rails 3 equivalents, I will refer back here next time I try and do this :)

Comment: The "queue already has default consumer" error isn't a Rails 3 problem, but an actual problem with how you're setting up the reply queue: you're sharing one AMQP channel between requests, but calling `subscribe` on that channel once per request.  You need to either open a channel per request, or redesign to have a single subscription to the queue (such as the Publisher singleton I mentioned below).  (You're also currently leaking subscriptions - you need to unsubscribe / close the per-request channel after the response comes in.)

Comment: Yep, I realized the AMQP resource handling was off. I played around a bit more with the channel-per-request approach, and ended up getting messages passing between the two apps reliably with each request. Unfortunately, the async callback only rendered the view on the first request; each subsequent request hung. Looking more deeply into async-rails, I found [this example](http://github.com/igrigorik/async-rails) from igrigorik containing a mounted async Sinatra app within the Rails app. I'm planning on digging into that next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the behaviour you want - have the client make a simple HTTP request, to which your web app responds asynchronously - but you need more tricks.  You need to use Thin's support for asynchronous responses:

```ruby
require "amqp"

class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    puts "[request] Sending a request..."

    WelcomeController.channel.default_exchange.publish("get.time",
      :routing_key => "amqpgem.examples.services.time",
      :message_id  => Kernel.rand(10101010).to_s,
      :reply_to    => WelcomeController.replies_queue.name)

    WelcomeController.replies_queue.subscribe do |metadata, payload|
      puts "[response] Response for #{metadata.correlation_id}: #{payload.inspect}"
      @message = payload.inspect

      # Trigger Rails response rendering now we have the message.
      # Tested in Rails 2.3; may or may not work in Rails 3.x.
      rendered_response = send_response.finish

      # Pass the response to Thin and make it complete the request.
      # env['async.callback'] expects a Rack-style response triple:
      # [status, headers, body]
      request.env['async.callback'].call(rendered_response)
    end

    # This unwinds the call stack, skipping the normal Rails response
    # rendering, all the way back up to Thin, which catches it and
    # interprets as "I'll give you the response later by calling
    # env['async.callback']".
    throw :async
  end

  def self.channel
    @channel ||= AMQP::Channel.new(AMQP.connection)
  end

  def self.replies_queue
    @replies_queue ||= channel.queue("reply", :exclusive => true, :auto_delete => true)
  end
end
```

As far as the client is concerned, the result is indistinguishable from your web app blocking on a synchronous call before returning the response; but now your web app can process many such requests concurrently.

### CAUTION!

Async Rails is an advanced technique; you need to know what you're doing.  Some parts of Rails do not take kindly to having their call stack abruptly dismantled.  The `throw` will bypass any Rack middlewares that don't know to catch and rethrow it ([here is a rather old partial solution](https://github.com/rkh/async-rack)).  ActiveSupport's development-mode class reloading will reload your app's classes after the `throw`, without waiting for the response, which can cause very confusing breakage if your callback refers to a class that has since been reloaded.  You'll also need to [ask ActionController nicely](https://github.com/mperham/phat/blob/master/config/initializers/disable_locking.rb) to allow concurrent requests.

### Request/response

You're also going to need to match up requests and responses.  As it stands, if Request 1 arrives, and then Request 2 arrives before Request 1 gets a response, then it's undefined which request would receive Response 1 (messages on a queue are distributed round-robin between the consumers subscribed to the queue).

You could do this by inspecting the correlation_id (which you'll have to explicitly set, by the way - RabbitMQ won't do it for you!) and re-enqueuing the message if it's not the response you were waiting for.  My approach was to create a persistent Publisher object which would keep track of open requests, listen for all responses, and lookup the appropriate callback to invoke based on the correlation_id.

### Alternative: just use HTTP

You're really solving two different (and tricky!) problems here: persuading Rails/thin to process requests asynchronously, and implementing request-response semantics on top of AMQP's publish-subscribe model.  Given you said this is for calling between two Rails apps, why not just use HTTP, which already has the request-response semantics you need?  That way you only have to solve the first problem.  You can still get concurrent request processing if you use a non-blocking HTTP client library, such as [em-http-request](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-http-request).